# multi file upload jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Im trying to upload multiple pictures with the following code

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="files" multiple accept="image/*">
```

And then checking it with:

```
$("#UploadThisPlease").validate({
    rules: {
        files: {
            filesize: 4194304,
        }
    },

    messages: {
        files: {
            filesize: "Max 4MB per picture",
        }
    },
```

It works in a different ways, though it does not work perfectly. how do I make this code better? Should i make it an remote check and then check it with PHP?

Comment: Please be more careful when tagging your questions.  The [tag:jquery-validate] plugin and the [tag:jquery-validation-engine] plugin are two totally different things.

Comment: What exactly does _"It works in a different ways, though it does not work perfectly"_ mean?

Comment: @Sparky It did work on single file, but i found out that it somehow sums all the pictures filesize, witch i dont want to have cause ive also added max 5 picture per upload

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:**

```
$("#UploadThisPlease").validate({
    rules: {
        files: {
            filesize: 4194304,  // <- no such rule or method
        }
    },
    .....
```

> *"It works in a different ways, though it does not work perfectly."*

Your code is not working very well because there is no such method called `filesize` in [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js) or its [`additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js).  [See documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

You will have to create this rule yourself somehow using [the `.addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"Should I make it a remote check and then check it with PHP?"*

Yes, that would certainly make it more reliable.

Comment: `$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
    // param = size (en bytes) 
    // element = element to validate (<input>)
    // value = value of the element (file name)
    return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param) 
});`

Comment: Im useing this now: `$.validator.addMethod('multifilesize', function(value, element, param) {
  // param = size (en bytes) 
  // element = element to validate (<input>)
  // value = value of the element (file name)
  var cnt = 0;
  jQuery.each(element.files, function(index, item) {
   // do something with `item` (or `this` is also `item` if you like)
   if (item.size >= param) {
    cnt++;
   }
  });
  return this.optional(element) || ((cnt == 0) ? true : false);
 });` maybe its not optimal, but it works as intended..